# problem creating new connectore

Tags: gwt

I am using gwt-connector for my project and i am trying to create new connector each time a button is clicked. Here is the code:

```
public class ERD1 implements EntryPoint {

public void onModuleLoad() {

    AbsolutePanel boundaryPanel = new AbsolutePanel();
    boundaryPanel.setPixelSize(1000, 1000);

    final Diagram d = new Diagram(boundaryPanel);

    Button b = new Button();
    b.addClickListener(new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(Widget sender) {
            SectionDecoration startDecoration = new SectionDecoration
            (SectionDecoration.DECORATE_ARROW);
                    SectionDecoration endDecoration = new SectionDecoration
            (SectionDecoration.DECORATE_ARROW); 

            Connector con = new Connector(10, 10, 10, 10, startDecoration, endDecoration);
            con.showOnDiagram(d);
        }

    });

    boundaryPanel.add(b, 10, 40);

    RootPanel.get().add(boundaryPanel);
}   
}
```

but when i click on the button i am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sections must be horizontal or vertical!
    at pl.tecna.gwt.connectors.client.Section.<init>(Section.java:44)
    at pl.tecna.gwt.connectors.client.Connector.recreateSections(Connector.java:226)
    at pl.tecna.gwt.connectors.client.Connector.showOnDiagram(Connector.java:162)
    at com.e.r.d.client.ERD1$1.onClick(ERD1.java:45)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListenerWrapper$WrappedClickListener.onClick(ListenerWrapper.java:245)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager$HandlerRegistry.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:65)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager$HandlerRegistry.access$1(HandlerManager.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:178)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:52)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:90)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1320)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventAndCatch(DOM.java:1299)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1262)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ie.IDispatchImpl.callMethod(IDispatchImpl.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ie.IDispatchProxy.invoke(IDispatchProxy.java:155)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ie.IDispatchImpl.Invoke(IDispatchImpl.java:294)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ie.IDispatchImpl.method6(IDispatchImpl.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:1925)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:2966)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.SwtHostedModeBase.processEvents(SwtHostedModeBase.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedModeBase.pumpEventLoop(HostedModeBase.java:557)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedModeBase.run(HostedModeBase.java:405)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode.main(HostedMode.java:232)
```

please can anyone tell me what is going wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all your points are all on the same point. How about trying different points? Like say `Connector con = new Connector(10, 15, 29, 100, startDecoration, endDecoration);`
 or something.

Answer (score 0):

I figured what went wrong.

```
 Connector con = new Connector(10, 10, 10, 10, startDecoration, endDecoration);
```

here i have 10,10,10,10 which was overlapping on one another. This was the reason for the error.